# Function not working with form element

Tags: php, mysqli

Please be gentle with me I'm just a newbie. Please tell me what's wrong why this function is not working. There's no error, just blank page.

```
<?php 

include("db.php");

$id = (integer)$_GET['id'];
echo $id;

function updateshowdata($stmt, $con){

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `firstname` FROM `MyGuests` where id =?");
$stmt->bind_param ('i',$id);
$stmt->execute ();
$stmt->bind_result ($firstname);


$updateshow = "<form method='post' action='updateprocess.php'>";

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$updateshow .= "<input type='text' name='firstname'  value='{$firstname}' >";

}

$updateshow .= "</form>";

echo $updateshow;

}
updateshowdata($stmt, $con);

?>
```

If I change this into below removing function, it is starting to work

```
<?php 

include("db.php");

$id = (integer)$_GET['id'];
echo $id;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `firstname` FROM `MyGuests` where id =?");
$stmt->bind_param ('i',$id);
$stmt->execute ();
$stmt->bind_result ($firstname);


$updateshow = "<form method='post' action='updateprocess.php'>";

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$updateshow .= "<input type='text' name='firstname'  value='{$firstname}' >";

}

$updateshow .= "</form>";

echo $updateshow;


?>
```

Comment: Check the value of `$id` in your function. Unexpected?

Comment: function need `return value` not echo

Comment: Sorry there's output actually `96<form method='post' action='updateprocess.php'></form>
` 96 is the id. The form is blank, the input element is missing.

Comment: I already tried that `return updateshowdata($stmt, $con);` and still the same. I have created same function using table with echo which on  [this] (http://pastebin.com/dj4Gxw2K). It is working, can't see why this one is not working with form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it works?

```
function updateshowdata($stmt, $con){
    $id = (int)$GET['id'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `firstname` FROM `MyGuests` where id =?");
    $stmt->bind_param ('i',$id);
    $stmt->execute ();
    $stmt->bind_result ($firstname);    


    $updateshow = "<form method='post' action='updateprocess.php'>";

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $updateshow .= "<input type='text' name='firstname'      value='{$firstname}' >";

}
```

Comment: Or pass `$id` as a third argument)

Comment: After function defintion. As in author's example

Comment: I forgot this one, the issue is about scope of variable. Thank you!